# How can we calculate time between any two simultaneously pressed keyboard keys?

Tags: android

I'm building an android application in which i want to calculate the time difference  between two key presses, each time the user types anything using keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

```
var lastKeyDownTime = 0L

override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event)
    val curKeyDownTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val interval = curKeyDownTime - lastKeyDownTime
    lastKeyDownTime = curKeyDownTime
}
```

BaseActivity